# Extracting negative and positive fractions from a string in C

Tags: c, fractions, negative-number

I have a line of string = `VOLTAGE 0.231023459 CURRENT -0.234334567 0.345511234`

How can I extract the negative fractions from the above line.
For positive values I can #define the index of the string and start parsing it.But there is no fixed sign for the values, the values can be negative as well as positive.
Is there a function to separate out negative and positive fractions from the above line. `isdigit()` only gives whether a char is digit or not without sign.

Comment: If the format is fixed, i.e. you know that the numbers are always the second, fourth and fifth fields, it's easy to split on space and discard the first and third fields and then use e.g. [`strtod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) to convert the numbers.

Comment: you may track `VOLTAGE` and `CURRENT` and check for `-` symbol is there after that or not. If `VOLTAGE` and `CURRENT` will always be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the way !

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

   float voltage,current1,current2;
   char voltages[20], current[20], dtm[100];

   strcpy( dtm, "VOLTAGE 0.231023459 CURRENT -0.234334567 0.345511234");
   sscanf( dtm, "%s %f %s %f %f", voltages,&voltage,current,&current1, &current2);

   printf("voltage = %f \n",voltage);
   printf("current1 = %f \n",current1);
   printf("current2 = %f \n",current2);

   return(0);
}
```

[ideone link here](http://ideone.com/naGsaq) !

so sscanf is the hero here !

Comment: 1) Could use `sscanf( dtm, " VOLTAGE %f CURRENT %f %f", &voltage, &current1, &current2);` 2) Robust code checks the result of `sscanf()`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how fixed your format is, do something like the following:

1. Use `strtok` to split on space characters
2. For each token, check to see if it's `VOLTAGE` or `CURRENT`, and decide where to store the next tokens accordingly.
3. If it's not `VOLTAGE` or `CURRENT`, use `strtod` to convert the token into a double, then save it in the appropriate place.

Answer (score 1):

You may track strings `VOLTAGE`and `CURRENT` if your string will always have format like this.
And check the `-` is there or not after a space. (You are already able to get digits.).

Or here is the better solution:

First skip the Non digits and then get the numbers using `strtok`:

```html
float get_Numbers(const char *str)
{

    /* Skip non-digit and handle the - cases in your string */
    while (*str && !(isdigit(*str) || ((*str == '-' || *str == '+') && isdigit(*(str + 1)))))
        str++;


    return strtod(str, NULL);
}
```